# Best way to snapshot MySQL data for audit trail

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I'm looking on advice for serializing information for an audit trail in a MySQL database.

I store events that have multiple relations, 6 to be exact. In an Events table. Therefore each record has 6 foreign keys in it. I'm wondering what the most scalable approach for serializing the related entities is, and storing it in this same Event record. This is because the data should persist even if the underlying records have been deleted or changed.

The API is Typescript and we interface the DB with Typeorm. My initial approach was going to be adding an @BeforeInsert event the loads all the related entities as json (some may or may not be present), and storing all of the entities in that format. Either using the "json" field, text, or doing some sort of blob conversion.

This will work for the foreseeable future, but I'm wondering what the most scalable approach would be. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know MySQL has an [Audit Log Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/audit-log-installation.html) feature? The documented one is part of their "Enterprise" upgrade, so you have to be a paying customer to use it. But it's a plugin, so there are open-source implementations too: https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/8.0/management/audit_log_plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the best solution, and maybe it will depend on your features / entities.

Here are some other options that you can use :

**Concerning the deleted record** : use softRemove / softDelete. It permits to never delete record in DB but set it as deleted for typeorm, using `@DeleteDateColumn` decorator.
Check the two following properties of typeorm : softRemove / softDelete and recover / restore.

**Concerning the updated record** : a workaround for the JSON stringify is to never update an entity and always make a copy and then update that copy (not clearly the best solution). Typeorm also use `@VersionColumn` decorator to persist versioning of the entity. You can change your code to take the older version of that entity.
Depending on your entity the table can grow very fast !

With these two options there is always a persistance of your data.
The advantage can be that it will be resilient for model migration as all your data will be stored as data and not JSON stringify text in a column.
The disadvantage is obviously the size of the database, the maintainability, and the development of it.

**Otherwise you can use a [subscriber](https://typeorm.io/listeners-and-subscribers)** that handles all modifications on the Event table. In this subscriber you can insert your modifications in a table name EventAudit or EvenLogWhatever something like "Name was updated from X to Y" or even more complex with an another database storing all version. In fact, you can do whatever you like inside this global subscriber as you can access the datasource, the entity, and the manager.

I hope it will help